# Call overriden super method twice to ensure valid state/result?

Tags: python, oop

I have 2 classes a `Child` class which inherits from a `Parent` class
The `Parent` class has a method called `getIt` which uses a property `param` to compute some value and return it. The value can be `None`. When the `Child` class inherits `Parent` it overrides `getIt` such that if `getIt`'s return value is `None` it changes `param` to some value that will definitely return a value other than `None`. So the objective is to never let an instance of `Child` class call to `getIt` return `None`. Here is how i have done it

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, some_params):
        self.param = some_value
    def getIt(self):
        val = # use self.param to do some logic   
        if val == []:
            raise RuntimeError("message")   

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, some_params):
        super(Child, self).__init__(some_params)
    def getIt(self):
        try:
            val = super(Child, self).getIt()
        except RuntimeError:
            self.param = some_other_value     # setting self.param to some_other_value will surely make getIt return a non empty list`
            val = super(Child, self).getIt()
        return val
```

Is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: @downvoter: This seems like a legit question. Why the downvote?

Comment: I was the downvoter. You've described this in such abstract terms that I have no idea whether what you're doing is sensible. What does `self.param` represent, and why is it reasonable to change its value (and therefore the state of the object) to some arbitrary value when a getter is called?

Comment: If the objective is just to not let `Child.getIt` return `None`, it would be more normal to have it just return a default value if `super(Parent, self).getIt` returns `None`, rather than modifying the object's state and calling `Parent.getIt` again. But without some more concrete explanation of what's going on here, I don't know whether that's a helpful remark.

Comment: Alternatively, if `Parent.getIt` returning `None` indicates that the object's state is invalid in some way, then you might want to try and detect that cheaply before calling `Parent.getIt` if `Parent.getIt` is expensive. But I'm going to stop randomly speculating now and wait for some detail.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree that to save typing a few more lines of code i have made it too abstract. I'll change the code

Comment: I'm with @MarkAmery on this - even with an edit, it just seems - umm, strange. It'll help if you could describe some context.

Comment: The restriction should go in parent class, child classes should only extend functionality.

Comment: Also, what is your purpose, why do you want this behaviour?